# Input CSS Codigo-Postal

Tags: html, css, input

Bom dia,

Eu gostaria de fazer com que o meu input text aceitasse só quatro números e dps desse colocar "-" e aceitar só mas três números.

Isso é possivel só com HTML e CSS?

Comment: O que deve acontecer quando é digitado uma letra por exemplo? ou _N_ caracteres a mais?

Comment: só permitir números e não deixar colocar caracteres a mais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somente com HTML e CSS acredito que não seria possível, mas com jQuery é fácil fazer isso. Segue exemplo:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var $campo = $("#cep");
        $campo.mask('00000-000', {reverse: true});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>

CEP <input type="text" id="cep" name="cep" />
```

Dessa forma o campo ficará limitado somente a números e à quantidade de dígitos solicitada.

Comment: funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o atributo `pattern` junto com o  `required`:

```html
<form>
<label for="CEP">CEP:
<input name="CEP" id="CEP" required pattern="\d{5}-\d{3}"/>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Lembrando que o CEP (salvo engano) são `5` digitos `-` e `3` digitos.
[Fonte](https://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/correios-de-a-a-z/cep-codigo-de-enderecamento-postal)

Comment: Você também pode usar o ```<input type="tel">``` pra limitar aos caracteres numéricos, principalmente em celulares.